# trying to access generator function features inside facebook graph api callback

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-saga, saga

This code is inside a redux saga file.

I'm trying to send the response back to the saga function but I can't.

```
new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
    '/me', {
        httpMethod: 'GET',
        version: 'v2.5',
        parameters: {
            'fields': {
                'string': 'email,first_name,last_name,id'
            }
        }
    }, startFacebookRegister);
```

the facebookRegister function

```
function * startFacebookRegister(err, res) {
    const { id, email, first_name, last_name } = res;
    yield put(initFacebookLogin.success(res));
}
```

Comment: where is the code situated? inside another saga generator? can you show more wrapping code?

Answer (score 0):

If we look at [`GraphRequestManager.start`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/js/FBGraphRequestManager.js#L98).

> ````
>     const that = this;
>     const callback = (error, result, response) => {
>       if (response) {
>         that.requestCallbacks.forEach((innerCallback, index, array) => {
>           if (innerCallback) {
>             // here it is called as a normal callback, not a generator
>             innerCallback(response[index][0], response[index][1]);
>           }
>         });
>       }
>       if (that.batchCallback) {
>         that.batchCallback(error, result);
>       }
>     };
>
>     NativeGraphRequestManager.start(this.requestBatch, timeout || 0, callback);   } ```
> ````

The callback you pass is invoked as a normal `Function`, as opposed to a `GeneratorFunction`.

And since they differ in how they are executed, that's why **nothing happens**, since your [`GeneratorFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), when invoked, is just instantiated and sits there until getting garbage collected.

So the preferred option to solve this, which is aligned with the `redux-saga` flow is using [`eventChannel`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/advanced/Channels.md#using-the-eventchannel-factory-to-connect-to-external-events), which keeps the flow inside `redux-saga` and is actually [advised for similar cases](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/613#issuecomment-258384017).

The other one, not so preferable, would be to just call raw `store.dispatch`, it obviously breaks through the abstraction levels and flow of `redux-saga`, but still gets the job done, by invoking some other `saga` action which can handle `call`ing your `startFacebookRegister` with the `response`.

#### EventChannel

We need to wrap the whole `GraphRequestManager...` block into an `eventChannel`, so we can redirect the `response` or `error` back into saga flow from the vendor control.

Can be something like this:

```js
import {
  cancelled,
  call,
  take,
  put
} from "redux-saga/effects";

import {
  eventChannel,
  END
} from 'redux-saga';

function* startFacebookRegister(err, res) {
  const {
    id,
    email,
    first_name,
    last_name
  } = res;
  yield put(initFacebookLogin.success(res));
}

function* graphRequestWrapper() {
  return eventChannel(emit => {
    const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
      '/me', {
        httpMethod: 'GET',
        version: 'v2.5',
        parameters: {
          'fields': {
            'string': 'email,first_name,last_name,id'
          }
        }
      }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          emit(new Error(err));
        } else {
          emit(res);
        }

        emit(END);
      });

    // BTW infoRequest variable should be instantiated before we
    // can add it with addRequest, just a side note
    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();

    return () => {
      // clean up
    };
  })
}


export function* mainSaga() {
  const chan = yield call(graphRequestWrapper);

  while (true) {
    try {
      const res = yield take(chan);
      yield call(startFacebookRegister, null, res);
    } catch (err) {
      yield call(startFacebookRegister, err);
    } finally() {
      if (yield cancelled()) chan.close()
    }
  }

}
```

### Store Dispatch

And with store, you can export your `store` from your `main.js` or `index.js` where you `createStore` it with all the reducers and middlewares, and use it here directly.

```js
import store "../exported/from/somewhere";

function* startFacebookRegister({payload}) {
  const {
    id,
    email,
    first_name,
    last_name
  } = payload;
  yield put(initFacebookLogin.success(res));
}

function graphRequestWrapper() {
  const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
    '/me', {
      httpMethod: 'GET',
      version: 'v2.5',
      parameters: {
        'fields': {
          'string': 'email,first_name,last_name,id'
        }
      }
    }, (err, response) => {
      store.dispatch({type: "INIT_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS_SAGA", payload: {...response}})
    });

  new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
}

function* mainSaga() {
  yield takeLatest("INIT_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS_SAGA", startFacebookRegister);

  yield call(graphRequestWrapper);
}
```